# jquery hide element when tab with class is visible

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to hide a div with jquery when an element is clicked.
Currently I have the below code which doesn't seem to work.

```
    $('#tabTwo').hasClass('current', function() {
    $(".featuredNews").css('display','none');
});
```

I should only do this when a tab with an id has a class as well as I need to do a few thing with this.

How can I solve this?

Thanks,

Sat

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#tabTwo.current').click(function () {
    $(".featuredNews").hide();
});
```

If the `.current` class can be added or removed dynamically, use `live()`

```
$('#tabTwo.current').live("click", function () {
    $(".featuredNews").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this to add a class which was set to display:none

$('#tabTwo a').click(function() {
        $("#tabOne").addClass('borderStrip');
    });

Thanks for all the help